# Pandas plot countries total and newcol

Tags: python, pandas

I am having an issue plotting multiple columns into a histogram plot

```
x1 = list(df[df['newcol'] == 0]['Country/Region'])
x2 = list(df[df['newcol'] == 1]['Country/Region'])

colors = ['r', 'c']
names = ['warm','cool']


plt.hist([x1, x2], bins = 1, normed=True,
         color = colors, label=names)
```

```
Country/Region Total  newcol
USA            450      0
Andorra        225      1
Bahamas        300      1 
Uk             150      0
Nigeria        189      0
```

I want to have the countries on the x axis the Total on the y axis and then the bars be colored based on the newcol value for example USA will be colored green since it is associated with 0 and Bahamas would be colored blue because of 1. The code I am using above is giving me the color but since there are so many countries in the Country/Region Column the graph is scrunched and also the y axis is not giving me the correct numbers

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need a bar plot instead of histogram

```
x1 = list(df[df['newcol'] == 0]['Country/Region'])
x2 = list(df[df['newcol'] == 1]['Country/Region'])
y1 = list(df[df['newcol'] == 0]['Total'])
y2 = list(df[df['newcol'] == 1]['Total'])

plt.bar(x1, y1, color='g')
plt.bar(x2, y2, color='b')
```

[image]

Is this what you needed?

Comment: this is good I was hoping for an overlapping histogram though but thank you

Comment: We could do that if USA had both 0 and 1 data. likewise every other country

Comment: ok one more question lets say I have 100 countries in a column with a 100 values in the newcol column how do I create the graph to fit all the data

Comment: maybe use scatter or bubble plot  like this one [link](https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*LVd1uNgqrNEs1_fL9lP9AA.png)  because barplot may become messy, If you have to use to use bar plot try to rotate labels on x-axis 90degrees